# AWS lambda configuration in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, serverless

I use below command to configure aws lambda

```
serverless config credentials --provider aws --key xxxx --secret xxxx
```

It says updated in **'.aws/credentials'**, But I could not find such file or directory.

How can I make it configurable to read from config file as it will be different for dev , qa or prod

I run below command to deploy

```
sls deploy
```

THanks

Answer (score 1):

Location for aws credential file in your machine

```
~/.aws
```

In Windows machine file path for **credential file** is **C:\Users\.aws**. Make sure .aws folder is not hidden

Credential information inside the **credential file** in .aws directory

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = yyyyy

[qa]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = yyyyy

[prod]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = yyyyy
```

You can manually *add multiple profiles [dev/test/preprod/qa]* in the following file.

Also you can add aws profile using the following command when **aws cli** is installed in your machine.

```
aws configure --profile prod

AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
Default region name [None]: us-west-2
Default output format [None]: ENTER
```

In order to **deploy serverless in AWS**, use the following command

```
serverless deploy //Use default profile and proceed deployment
serverless deploy --aws-profile qa //Deploy in QA environment  
serverless deploy --aws-profile prod //Deploy in Production environment
```

For more detailed information about serverless deployment, kindly go through the following documentation [Serverless Deployment](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/credentials/)